# Why hair is not moving with bone

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, hair, pose-mode

In pose mode when i move bone  object is moving with it but hair is not moving here the picture of my problem[image]

Comment: in the modifier Stack, put the Particle System under the Armature modifier (or above, I don't remember)

Answer (score 2):

Hair systems are tied to objects by a modifier, so does the armature deformation. They position in the stack affects how they interract with each other.

In you case, you need your hair simulation to generate from the mesh as it is deformed by the armature modifier. So you have to make use the hair particles modifier is AFTER the armature deform modifier.

In addition, you might also want to enable `Use Modifier Stack` in the hair settings:

[image: use modifier stack]

If you have a subdivision modifier and need to comb the hair:
Make sure the preview subdivision level is the same as your render when you comb your hair.
Or alternatively: create a duplicated mesh object that sits just inside the skin of your emitting object, and make that one emit the hair insead of the actual main object (also disable its display in the particles settings, so you don't waste precious render resources rendering that invisible mesh).

Comment: Thx, solved it for me.